# Is every isomorphism a homeomorphism on R^n?

Tags: general-topology

Is every isomorphism a homeomorphism on R^n (as real vector space)? In particular, is a rotation a homeomorphism?(w.r.t usual topology)

Comment: Isomoprhism as what? Abelian group? Real vector space?

Comment: As real vector space.

Comment: Do you know about topological groups or category theory? This would admit elegant more general proofs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Indeed, this follows since linear maps between finite dimensional spaces are continuous.

**Claim:** Let $f\colon \mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^n$ be an isomorphism of vector spaces. Then $f$ is a homeomorphism.

**Proof:**
Since $f$ is a linear map between finite dimensional spaces, it is continuous. Since $f$ is a bijection, $f^{-1}$ exists and is linear. Thus $f^{-1}$ is continuous, so $f$ is a homeomorphism.